# Flash AS3 and XML: way to fix line breaks in htmlText that uses <b> tags in the xml?

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, htmltext

I'm importing text in from an xml file and i'm using htmlText to try to keep some styling with  tags. I have both the regular and bold face font embedded, and the bolding works fine. The problem is that it ads spaces around the words in bold like a paragraph indent and then makes a line-break after them. What's going on, is there a way to fix?

```
fromxmlText.htmlText = theXML.contenttext;
```

If I pull the text in from a txt file it will work fine, but taking it out of an xml file causing funky formatting. lil' help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To add HTML into XML you must use [CDATA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CDATA) blocks otherwise the HTML is considered part of the XML document.

e.g.

```
<root>
    <someHtml><![CDATA[I can contain<br />html tags]]></someHtml>
    <somePlainText>I cannot contain html tags since they will be 
                   seen as XML nodes</somePlainText>
</root>
```

Also make sure you are saving your XML files with unix line endings and encoded as utf-8. If you are using windows line endings (`\r\n`) then Flash tends to double space newlines. Your editor should allow you to specify the line endings.

Comment: +1. But just to be safe, it's a good idea to replace `\r\n` with `\n` in the code (in case someone else edits the xml and forgets to change line endings).

Comment: I wasn't using the \n or \r. just the <b> tags. This suggestion totally fixes my issue. I figured that it was being read as nodes, but I didn't know how to fix it. Thanks!

Comment: @HeroicNate. Ok. But if someone edits the XML, it's possible that they break text into lines if it's too long (even though they put a <br> as well). Depending on your editor configuration, that will be translated to a newline or a carriage return + newline. I've seen that happen, that's why I suggested the extra check.

Answer (score 1):

I was importing a dynamic rss feed into a flash ad of mine that had html tags embedded. I was having the same problem. I used regex to find and replace. Here is the function I was using. you can prob use my regex code in there to do the same thing. It seems like we were having the same problem. Hope this helps:

function Parserover_feature(rover_feature:XML):void {

```
var s:String = rover_feature.items.item[0].article;
s = s.replace(/(?:<br>)+/gi, '<br>');
s = s.replace(/\n/g, '');
container.info_txt.htmlText = s
//trace (s);
```

}

Comment: Thanks for this regex - just solved my issue when ignoreWhitespace would just get rid of all line breaks :)

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say without seeing your XML, but try fiddling with the [global XML properties](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/XML.html) especially [ignoreWhitespace](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/XML.html#ignoreWhitespace). Depending on your line endings, you may also need to strip them before putting the text into the textfield.

Answer (score 0):

if you are embedding from xml then make sure that you are using CDATA tags to show preformatted code, otherwise you are outputting the content of multiple nodes in XML.

see [w3 schools](http://www.w3schools.com/xmL/xml_cdata.asp) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

Also make sure your textField is set to `multiline` before you set your textField.htmlText = xml with 
 i.e.

```
var myText:TextField = new TextField();
myText.multiline = true;
myText.htmlText = (your xml node with the <br/ >);
addChild(myText);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This would probably be more appropriate as a comment than another answer.